# Error trying to rotate an image in Matlab using INTERP2 funcion

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to perform an image rotation without embedded Matlab's function. 
But I'm still getting this error:
**Error using  .'** 
**Transpose on ND array is not defined. Use PERMUTE instead.**

**Error in interp2 (line 130)**
        **V = V.';**

But I don't know why there is such a mistake and likewise I don't know how to customize the function **interp2** or **PERMUTE** to make it functional (I have used **help** in Matlab).

Could you please help to customize the code?

Thanks in advance!

```
clc; clear all; close all;

input_image = imread('mri.png');
Z = double(input_image);

Size = size(Z);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:Size(2), 1:Size(1));

%Center of an image
c = Size(end:-1:1)/2;

%Angle of rotation
angle = 45;
t = angle*pi/180;

%Making the rotation
ct = cos(t);
st = sin(t);
Xi = c(1) + ct*(X - c(1)) - st*(Y - c(2));
Yi = c(2) + st*(X - c(1)) + ct*(Y - c(2));

%Interpolation
Zi = interp2(X, Y, Z, Xi, Yi);

figure()
subplot(121); imshow(I); title('Original image');
subplot(122); imshow(uint8(Zi)); title('Rotated image without embedded 
function');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Z` is a 3D matrix and `interp2` only works for 2D matrices. So you have to do the interpolation for each colour separately, and recombine them:

```
%Interpolation
Zir = interp2(X, Y, Z(:,:,1), Xi, Yi);
Zig = interp2(X, Y, Z(:,:,2), Xi, Yi);
Zib = interp2(X, Y, Z(:,:,3), Xi, Yi);
Zi = cat(3, Zir, Zig, Zib);
```